# pgloader exit without error (MySQL 5.7 to PostgreSQL 11.6)

Tags: mysql, postgresql, pgloader

I try to migrate **from MySQL 5.7 to PostgreSQL 11.6** with [pgloader](https://pgloader.readthedocs.io/) on **Ubuntu 18.04**.

```sh
pgloader -v -d mysql://mysqluser:secret@localhost/dbnamesource pgsql:///postgres:secret@localhost/dbnametarget
```

MySQL and PostgreSQL user exist and can login on command line. Both have GRANT rights.

The above scripts output:

```sh
sb-impl::*default-external-format* :UTF-8
tmpdir: #P"/tmp/pgloader/"
2019-12-17T08:29:55.019000Z NOTICE Starting pgloader, log system is ready.
2019-12-17T08:29:55.029000Z INFO Starting monitor
2019-12-17T08:29:55.033000Z INFO Stopping monitor
```

The target database is empty.

Where ist the problem or what can i do to find the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah, there is one slash too much (after `pgsql:`). Now it works:

```sh
pgloader -v -d mysql://mysqluser:secret@localhost/dbnamesource pgsql://postgres:secret@localhost/dbnametarget
```